# Cannot see the message body in activeMq when message sent through wso2 esb

Tags: activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I am new to this.I created a jms message store in wso2 esb and sent a message to it.message was received in activeMq but cannot see the message body in Activemq.

Message Details:
org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.commons.StorableMessage@79f1d1d8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ESB using jms message stores to store messages as objects, you can't see the message body via activemq. You can use [message processor](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Adding+a+Message+Processor) to get messages from the store and then use it in whatever the process you want.

As ESB use message store purely for storing process, it will use exact format. That is why you have to use processors to work with stored messages.